# Second master's degree in another field without bachelors

Tags: masters, university, united-kingdom, second-degree

Question: Can I study master's degree in another field (or adjacent field) if I have a master's degree already without a bachelor degree?

Explanation: At the moment I am studying master's degree in computer science while skipping bachelor degree based on work experience. And I was wondering if is is possible to study for example Math's or Physic's master (probably direction a bit more connected with CS) directly ? Maybe some extra courses would be needed as well?

Comment: For which country are you asking for?

Comment: For United Kingdom, but i'd say answer related to Canada, US if not UK would be very beneficial as well.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: Probably ok, so long as you demonstrate graduate-level competency and have good undergraduate grades in the adjacent field.

Long answer: Graduate work (at the Master's level) looks very different from undergraduate, so the key is demonstrating, via your application to the program (support from a faculty member in that area goes a long way too--so contacting such a person and discussing it with them before your application is important), that you are capable of self-learning and can pick up the introductory principles of the adjacent field as you go.